# How do insert data into this schema?

Tags: node.js, express, prisma

Below is my prisma schema

```
 model Allegations {
  allegation_id   String     @id @db.VarChar(200)
  faculty         String?    @db.VarChar(200)
  department      String?    @db.VarChar(200)
  course          String?    @db.VarChar(200)
  instructor      String?    @db.VarChar(200)
  instructorEmail String?    @db.VarChar(200)
  instructorPh    String?    @db.VarChar(200)
  details         String?    @db.VarChar(200)
  allegationDate  DateTime?  @db.DateTime(0)
  violationDate   DateTime?  @db.DateTime(0)
  Students        Students[]
}

model Students {
  id            String       @id @db.VarChar(200)
  student_name  String?      @db.VarChar(200)
  banner        String?      @db.VarChar(200)
  allegation_id String?      @db.VarChar(200)
  Allegations   Allegations? @relation(fields: [allegation_id], references: [allegation_id], onDelete: Restrict, onUpdate: Restrict, map: "Students_ibfk_1")

  @@index([allegation_id], map: "allegation_id")
}
```

So far I got his but getting errors. I also tried inserting seperately into allegations and students, but the insert in students doesn't go through.

```
prisma.allegations.create({
        data: {
            allegation_id:key,
            faculty: Faculty,
            department: Department,
            course: Course,
            instructor: Instructor,
            instructorPh: PhoneNumber,
            instructorEmail: InstructorEmail,
            details: Details,
            allegationDate: date,
            violationDate: OffenceDate,
            Students:{
                create:{
                     student_name: 'kn',
                    banner: '555555'
                },
            }
        } 
     });
```

Comment: "*getting errors*" Why have you elected *not* to include any of this error information in accordance with [ask]?

Comment: Because this isn't rocket science? I just want to know the right way of inserting when there's. foreign key involved

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your code snippet slightly, I was able to correctly insert a record into the database. Also, you have to specify the student ID because you do not have the `@default` attribute on the Student schema. Find the modified code below

```js
const allegation  = await prisma.allegations.create({
  data: {
    allegation_id:"1",
    faculty: "Science",
    department: "Biochemistry",
    course: "BCH101",
    instructor: "John Doe",
    instructorPh: "+231345678",
    instructorEmail: "johndoe@test.com",
    details: "some details",
    allegationDate: new Date('2022','07', '31'),
    violationDate: new Date('2022','08', '01'),
    Students:{
        create:{
             id: 'std1',
             student_name: 'Test Student',
            banner: '555555'
        },
    }
}
})
```